# List of Mobile Elements

Tags: c#, list, appium

I'm using this to locate one android element:

```
[FindsByAndroidUIAutomator(ClassName = "android.widget.EditText")]
[FindsByIOSUIAutomation(Accessibility = "")]
public IMobileElement<AppiumWebElement> PhoneField;
```

Its working and returns one element

But on the screen I have 9 such elements and I need list of these elements

I tried this but it returns null - 0 elements

```
[FindsByAndroidUIAutomator(ClassName = "android.widget.EditText")]
[FindsByIOSUIAutomation(Accessibility = "")]
public List<IMobileElement<AppiumWebElement>> PhoneField;`
```

Comment: You have a two dimensional array and may need to use SelectMany to flatten array to one dimension.

Comment: I try this:      
     public IList<AppiumWebElement>

And working :D